# iOS and Anyline EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, memory-management, anyline

I link in my iOS project the Anyline framework. In the sample source code of the framework I build and run app without errors, but if I try to import it in my project and run app, I've the runtime error EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
I try to print and read the backtrace, but I can't see where is the error. Can you help me?

Here the content of the backtrace:

```
 thread #12, queue = 'com.apple.avfoundation.videodataoutput.bufferqueue', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2b002010040)
frame #0: 0x000000010016f858 ARAMIS`cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const + 56
frame #1: 0x000000010062af30 ARAMIS`-[AnylineVideoView convertBGRABufferToImage:] + 1772
frame #2: 0x000000010062a11c ARAMIS`-[AnylineVideoView _processBufferFromDevice:] + 612
frame #3: 0x0000000100629e04 ARAMIS`-[AnylineVideoView captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] + 72
frame #4: 0x000000018bca1310 AVFoundation`-[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput _handleRemoteQueueOperation:] + 308
frame #5: 0x000000018bca114c AVFoundation`__47-[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput _updateRemoteQueue:]_block_invoke + 100
frame #6: 0x0000000186b71f68 CoreMedia`__FigRemoteOperationReceiverCreateMessageReceiver_block_invoke + 260
frame #7: 0x0000000186b90e9c CoreMedia`__FigRemoteQueueReceiverSetHandler_block_invoke.2 + 224
frame #8: 0x00000001022f9a10 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
frame #9: 0x0000000102305a84 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_continuation_pop + 552
frame #10: 0x00000001023141f8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 204
frame #11: 0x00000001022fba60 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_source_invoke + 828
frame #12: 0x0000000102307128 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 692
frame #13: 0x00000001022fd634 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 852
frame #14: 0x0000000102307128 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 692
frame #15: 0x00000001022fd634 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 852
frame #16: 0x0000000102308358 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_item + 276
frame #17: 0x000000010231057c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 764
frame #18: 0x0000000183312fbc libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 772
frame #19: 0x0000000183312cac libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 4
```

Here the code:

```
#import "ALISBNScanViewController.h"
#import <Anyline/Anyline.h>

NSString * const kISBNLicenseKey = Anyline_LICENSE_KEY;

@interface ALISBNScanViewController ()<AnylineOCRModuleDelegate>
// The Anyline module used for OCR
@property (nonatomic, strong) AnylineOCRModuleView *ocrModuleView;

@end

@implementation ALISBNScanViewController
/*
 We will do our main setup in viewDidLoad. Its called once the view controller is getting ready to be displayed.
 */
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Set the background color to black to have a nicer transition
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.title = @"Text Recognition";

    // Initializing the module. Its a UIView subclass. We set the frame to fill the whole screen
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, frame.size.width, frame.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
    self.ocrModuleView = [[AnylineOCRModuleView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    ALOCRConfig *config = [[ALOCRConfig alloc] init];
    config.tesseractLanguages = @[@"eng_no_dict", @"deu"];
    config.charWhiteList = @"PMMDOBCPSKA1234_/ ";
    config.scanMode = ALAuto;

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [self.ocrModuleView setupWithLicenseKey:kISBNLicenseKey delegate:self ocrConfig:config error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert(success, @"Setup Error: %@", error.debugDescription);
    }

    NSString *confPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"isbn_config" ofType:@"json"];
    ALUIConfiguration *isbnconf = [ALUIConfiguration cutoutConfigurationFromJsonFile:confPath];
    self.ocrModuleView.currentConfiguration = isbnconf;

    [self.view addSubview:self.ocrModuleView];    
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self startAnyline];
}

/*
 Cancel scanning to allow the module to clean up
 */
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.ocrModuleView cancelScanningAndReturnError:nil];
}

- (void)startAnyline {
    NSError *error;
    BOOL success = [self.ocrModuleView startScanningAndReturnError:&error];
    if( !success ) {
        NSAssert(success, @"Start Scanning Error: %@", error.debugDescription);
    }
}

#pragma mark -- AnylineOCRModuleDelegate

/*
 This is the main delegate method Anyline uses to report its results
 */
- (void)anylineOCRModuleView:(AnylineOCRModuleView *)anylineOCRModuleView
               didFindResult:(ALOCRResult *)result {
    NSString *label = result.result;

    DLog(@"LABEL:%@",label);


    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testo riconosciuto: %@",label];


    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Testo riconosciuto" message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction* okBtn = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [self startAnyline];
    }];


    [alert addAction:okBtn];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [self.ocrModuleView startScanningAndReturnError:&error];

    NSAssert(success, @"We failed starting: %@",error.debugDescription);
}

@end
```

Thanks

Comment: Without code it is hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: @JohnTracid sorry, I've edited the question...the app crashes when I call startScanningAndReturnError

Comment: Can you add all your linked frameworks and libraries and other build settings (ex. Other_linker_flags) which could be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I've found the solution few days ago....the solution is exactly the Other_linker_flags build settings....thanks for support